# XF: Equivalent to Page OnAppearing event when app is resumed

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

When App is resumed, XF calls OnAppearing on the Page.

Is there something equivalent to this in Prism?
I am expecting some interface, something similar to `INavigatedAware`

How can I know in the view-model that app was resumed and the view-model is for the current Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for OnAppearing/OnDisappearing has been added in Prism 7 via `IPageLifecycleAware`. Simply add it to any ViewModel and it will be called when the Page Appearing/Disappearing events are invoked.

Remember that there is also `IApplicationLifecycleAware`, which will give you support for OnSleep and OnResume.

Comment: Thanks. With `IPageLifecycleAware` I wonder how will it be possible to differentiate between page being navigated to and page being resumed because of app resume

Comment: I see even in v6 there's already a `IApplicationLifecycle` which has `OnSleep` and `OnResume` Is there are a problem with these?

Comment: These are meant for different things. As the names suggest one is Page focused and the other Application focused. If your goal is to handle Application resume specifically then you want IApplicationLifecycleAware

Comment: @DanS. is there something like `OnPagedLoaded` i.e., all the controls in the page have been instantiated already?